# Match first occurrence of two words that appear in string using regex or tokenization. Also taking into account distance between words(5 words)

Tags: python, regex

I need help matching the two words "hello" and "hope" in mystring, but only counting the first occurrence in the string. The max distance they could be from each other is 5 words. Appreciate any help!

`mystring = "hello bob nice weather hope you have a good day. hello jan hope weather is nice"`

This is what I have so far. I'm wanting the result to only catch the first occurrence of "hello" and "hope" and stop matching afterwards.

`pattern = re.findall('\bhello(?:\W+\w+){0,5}\W+hope\b', mystring)`

Comment: Does it have to be regex? Probably easier to solve with tokenization in the mix.

Comment: Yes it can be tokenization @MattL.

Comment: In that case, try it with tokenization, or simply remove the punctuation and `split` the input.  The regex is hard to read and maintain, as you've already learned.

Comment: Could you help with the tokenization? @Prune

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: `"\b"` is a backspace char. You need `r"\b"`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do in a single line of code with RegEx, but you can do part of it with regex and have an additional line of code using list comprehension.

```
mystring = "hello bob nice weather hope you have a good day. hello jan hope weather is nice"
pattern = re.findall('hello(?:\W+\w+){0,5}\W+hope', mystring)
pattern

['hello bob nice weather hope', 'hello jan hope']


new_pattern = [x for x in pattern if len(x.split()) == 5]
new_pattern

['hello bob nice weather hope']
```

Comment: Thanks! @David Erickson